# Get best possible location in certain time

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play-services, android-location

In my app I need to get users location (one shot, not continuously track), to calculate routes. So the location needs to be as accurate as possible but I do not want to keep user waiting too long when my app tries to get the accurate location.

Im using Google Play services location api like this:

```
LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
locationRequest.setNumUpdates(1); 
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,locationRequest, this);
mLocationHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 15000); // Time out location request
```

I have Handler mLocationHandler, which cancels locationRequest after 15 second, as I do not want to keep user waiting too long.

Is there any way, how I can try to get not so accurate location if the high accuracy location times out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this after the time out,

```
Location currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

It will give you the last known location and check if the accuracy is better than what you got from the location updates.

Update your updates something like this:

```
final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
        .setInterval(16)         
        .setFastestInterval(16)    // 16ms = 60fps
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

This will ensure that you will have updates. You can then reduce your timeouttime not more than a second should be enough. Then you can remove the locationupdaterequest like this:

```
if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {            
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,this);             
}
```

Comment: In your location update you probably want to request as many locations as possible in your interval(delay) Then choose the best one.

Comment: Then problem is that in some cases I do not get any location updates in my interval (15s). Maybe I need to set the priority something other thatn high accuracy?

Comment: change your locationUpdate. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Usually the location is returned within seconds, but from analytics I can see that my timeout is hit sometimes. I do not know is the user inside large building or what, but any case the app is not able to get the location. In your updated answer, there is not much difference to my original LocationRequest, removed setNumUpdates. Does this make any difference in scenarios where im not able to get any location updates in my original request?

Comment: If a service is available this will force it to make updates each 16ms after the first update. But is is never more thant few seconds...

Comment: Thanks! But if i set the setNumUpdates to 1, does it make any difference than it will stop location updates after the first update?

Comment: I am not sure. I use this in my app and it always gives me updates when a location service is available.

Answer (score 2):

I use external library for this: [Android-ReactiveLocation](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation). Check the `Cooler examples` section which presents exactly what you want:

```
LocationRequest req = LocationRequest.create()
                         .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                         .setExpirationDuration(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(LOCATION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS))
                         .setInterval(LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL);

Observable<Location> goodEnoughQuicklyOrNothingObservable = locationProvider.getUpdatedLocation(req)
            .filter(new Func1<Location, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(Location location) {
                    return location.getAccuracy() < SUFFICIENT_ACCURACY;
                }
            })
            .timeout(LOCATION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Observable.just((Location) null), AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .first()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

goodEnoughQuicklyOrNothingObservable.subscribe(...);
```